# HQL missing keyword

Tags: java, sql, hql

I've been looking for hours but can't find what is missing in the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Request r JOIN r.status status WHERE r.uniqueId = '123456'
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Comment: Your join does not make sense at all.

Comment: JOIN r.status ?

Comment: The ON clause is missing.

Comment: even in HQL? I agree for SQL. EDIT: I looked it up, ON clause is not needed for HQL...

Comment: It does make sense in HQL

Comment: ; in the end maybe ?

Comment: No, I tried that too

Comment: Is this select statement the entire code you are using ?

Comment: Doesn't Oracle still want the ON clause?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the keyword `AS` according to [Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms) :

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Request r INNER JOIN 
     r.status AS status -- AS missed
WHERE r.uniqueId = '123456'
```

Comment: I still get the exception